# Checking for a directory in results returned from attributesOfItemAtPath

Tags: objective-c

In the following code, I am scanning a directory for its contents and am attempting to ascertain whether a child is a directory or file:

```
NSString *child = [dir stringByAppendingPathComponent:candidate];
NSDictionary *candidate_attr = [self.manager attributesOfItemAtPath:child error:nil];
if(candidate_attr.fileType == NSFileTypeDirectory)
  [stack addObject:child];
```

Is it legitimate to use the pointer comparison above with NSFileTypeDirectory or should I be using the compare method?  I should point out that the above code appears to be working as I expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSDictionary fileType` is an `NSString`. Therefore it is an object type. Therefore you really need to use `isEqual:` (or `isEqualToString:`).

```
if ([candidate_attr.fileType isEqualToString:NSFileTypeDirectory]) {
    // it's a directory
}
```

BTW - if it appears to be working with `==` it is merely due to some possible optimization with the strings that can't be relied upon.

Another way to check if a file is a directory is to do this:

```
NSString *child = [dir stringByAppendingPathComponent:candidate];
BOOL isDir = NO;
if ([self.manager fileExistsAtPath:child isDirectory:&isDir]) {
    // child exists
    if (isDir) {
        // it's a directory
    } else {
        // it's not a directory
    }
} else {
    // child does't exist
}
```